# Как добавить элементу CheckBox к событию checked обработчик события не через двойного клика WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

Помогите начинающему советом где и как искать.
Проект WPF состоит из `MainWindow.xaml`, в котором разметка и отдельно класс `ViewModel.cs`, в котором прописаны свойства которые биндятся к форме.

На форме есть елемент

```xml
<CheckBox 
   Name="CB_IsTreeView"
   Content="CheckBox" 
   HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
   Margin="303,45,0,0" 
   VerticalAlignment="Top" 
   Checked="?????"  
/>
```

Пытаюсь добавить событие `Checked` обработчик на метод в классе `ViewModel`.

```cs
public void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Хочу обратить внимание что `MainWindow.xaml` и `ViewModel.cs` связаны только через `Binding`.

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"  
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
```

**Вопрос:** как связать событие `Checked` с методом `CheckBox_Checked` без использавания `MainWindow.xaml.cs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Checked` - это не свойство, это событие, а свойство - это `IsChecked`.

В MVVM это делается примерно так. Обработчик не нужен (совсем).

```cs
public class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

public class ViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _treeViewChecked;

    public bool TreeViewChecked
    {
        get => _treeViewChecked;
        set
        {
            _treeViewChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            // сюда можно добавить свой код, только осторожно,
            // код не должен выполняться долго
            OnTreeViewChecked();
        }
    }

    private void OnTreeViewChecked()
    {
        // Использовать MessageBox в ViewModel - плохая практика, но работать будет, показываю для наглядности.
        MessageBox.Show("Новое значение чекбокса: " + TreeViewChecked);
    }

    // ... ваш код
}
```

Нужно назначить не событие, а привязать свойство. Вот это `Name="CB_IsTreeView"` больше не нужно, уберите его.

```xml
<CheckBox 
   Content="CheckBox" 
   HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
   Margin="303,45,0,0" 
   VerticalAlignment="Top" 
   IsChecked="{Binding TreeViewChecked}"  
/>
```

При этом теперь вы можете поставить или снять галку даже програмно из `ViewModel`.

```cs
TreeViewChecked = true;
```

Так же к этому же свойству можно прибиндить любой другой контрол, если например вам нужно задать чекбоксом видимость `TreeView`, то можно сделать это в стиле.

```xml
<TreeView ...>
    <TreeView.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TreeView">
            <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="Visible"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TreeViewChecked}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.Style>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: благодарю за развернутый ответ, вопрос, как мне отслеживать что значение TreeViewChecked было изменено? В принципе, вопрос именно к этому сводится. по значению TreeViewChecked = true должен срабатывать метод... По этому и зацепился за событие Checked.

Comment: Вопрос поправил.

Comment: @parabol Вам ведь указали в примере `сюда можно добавить свой код, только осторожно`, что мешает туда добавить вызов нужного метода?

Comment: @parabol после `OnPropertyChanged();` пишите свой код, он вызовется как раз тогда, когда пользователь нажмет на чекбокс. Ну или когда вы измените свойство из кода.

Comment: @parabol `Вопрос: как связать событие Checked с методом CheckBox_Checked без использавания MainWindow.xaml.cs` - никак. А как можно вместо этого - я вам и показал.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!)

Comment: Тут на самом деле есть еще один вариант, но его мало кто использует просто так. Так, как идет реализация INPC, то можно подписаться, например в конструкторе, на событие `PropertyChanged`, в котором можно будет взять допустим `e.PropertyName`, сверить и сделать свою логику на этом всем.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ очень популярная в xamarin, да.